# VBA Use Active Row Number in a Selection

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to write a macro that will take my active cell's row number and use it in a selection. E.G. if my active row is A**10** I want the macro to select A1:N**10**

Comment: Any reason `ActiveCell.Row` isn't working?

Comment: Not sure. I tried to use Range("A1:NActiveCell.Row").Select to select the range but that did not work. Is there another way to select the range where ActiveCell.Row will work?

Comment: `Range("A1:N" & ActiveCell.Row)`.

Answer (score 0):

Just to close this question out:

```
Range("A1:N" & ActiveCell.Row)
```